# require only specific service from a mono-repo package in node

Tags: node.js, package.json, monorepo

I have a package with several utils services. I have publish and used it many times. Now the package got to heavy to use and I want to use only several parts of it. Is then an option in node to require only chosen services/folders to be imported during execution.